# Knob JS always return NaN while value is a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I have number value returning from my backend but it my knob it return as `NaN` and I've searched this website and googled it but all I got was the way to test if my value `isNaN` or not, which is not.

`Code`

```
console.log('As of String: ', data.inProgress.toString());
console.log('As of Number: ', data.inProgress);
if (isNaN(data.inProgress)) {
  console.log('Not a Number!');
} else {
  console.log('Is a Number!');
}
```

`Result`

[image: one]

`Usage`

```
$('#knobProgress')
  .val(data.inProgress)
  .trigger(
    'configure',
    {
      "min":0,
      "max":data.total,  //2
    }
);
```

## Update

If I comment `trigger` part from my code it works just fine, whatever the issue is, is coming from trigger part.

`This works`

```
$('#knobProgress')
.val(data.inProgress);
// .trigger(
//     'configure',
//     {
//         "min":0,
//         "max":data.total,  //2
//     }
// );
```

Comment: `isNaN('')  // false`

Comment: @ksav so that means the issue is not my value, issue is in the code which i shared update, please advise based on my update part.

Comment: What is `data.total`?

Comment: @ksav it's equal to `2` you can use static number `2` if you want to test

Comment: Maybe try to create a repro then.

Answer (score 1):

isNaN is used to test the NaN itself,only isNaN(NaN) return true

Comment: see my update please